# disable all buttons inside a repeating div

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

So i have a Jquery template that display multiple results to the user, at the bottom of the results is a div which i am using to store some buttons.

Now, depending on the status of a record, i want to hide all buttons within the e div's, but for some reason, the following does nothing:

```
$('#violationFooter').find('input,button').prop('disabled', true);
```

I've tried several other settings, the following hide the parent div

```
   $('#violationResults').hide();
```

but this doesn't do anything either

```
   $('#violationResults #violationFooter').hide();
```

I'm at a loss

***EDIT***

```
   <script id="violationtmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <div class="row user-infos ${MessageId}">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-danger">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Violation</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                    <table class="table table-user-information" id="scrollable" style="height: 200px;">
                                        <tbody>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="violationFooter" class="panel-footer">
                            <button class="btn  btn-success btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Good guy?" onclick="" ><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

***EDIT ***

This is the call to populate the Template

```
function GetViolations(messageId) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetViolationMessages",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ messageId: messageId }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error:
                    function(xhr) {

                        var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                        if (xhr.status === 401 && contentType.toLowerCase().indexOf("text/html") >= 0) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    },
                success: function(msg) {
                    // Need to work out a way of refreshing the screen

                    $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {

                        $('#violationtmpl').tmpl(item).appendTo('#violationResults');

                    });


                    var panels = $('.user-infos');
                    var panelsButton = $('.dropdown-user');
                    panels.hide();

                    //Click dropdown
                    panelsButton.click(function() {
                        //get data-for attribute
                        var dataFor = $(this).attr('data-for');
                        var idFor = $(dataFor);

                        //current button
                        var currentButton = $(this);
                        idFor.slideToggle(400, function() {
                            //Completed slidetoggle
                            if (idFor.is(':visible')) {
                                currentButton.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up text-muted"></i>');
                            } else {
                                currentButton.html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down text-muted"></i>');
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                }
            });
        };
```

***EDIT***

rendered HTML image

[image]

Comment: can you post your html in a fiddlejs?

Comment: Make a fiddle to demonstrate your problem

Answer (score 2):

**try this:**

```
$('#violationFooter button').hide()
```

or better

```
$('.panel-footer button').hide()
```

Comment: @CSharpNewBee can you create a jsfiddle of your rendered html and put the link here or in your question? thanks.

Comment: Nothing Sunny. this isn't making any sense. I'm going to try and find a tool to monitor the dom, something must be overriding it

Comment: @CSharpNewBee: why don't you put your rendered HTML in a fiddle and share the link?

Comment: Hi Sunny, i've found the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<button class="btn  btn-success btn-xs hideButton" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Good guy?" onclick="" >
  <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i>
</button>
<button class="btn  btn-success btn-xs" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Good guy?" onclick="" >
  <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i>
</button>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.hideButton').css("display", "none");
$('.hideButton').hide();
```

u can add your own class to the buttons that need to hide.. for eg here first button wll hide second will not!

Comment: nor any of these Chriz. The strange thing here is that these should all work right? Perhaps it's the way JQuery Templates renders the buttons

Comment: nothing, this is so odd. i can hide the parent pnl but nothing inside the template code

Comment: Chriz, see rendered HTML above

Comment: @CSharpNewBee i tested in my local system, these all will do the trick.. sorry i didnt got y its not wrkng for u..

Comment: is it because there are multiples? Basically the while html above is wrapped in a foreach, so there is more than one instance of div id=violationFooter - which i know should be unique, but i'd of thought the class calls would of worked.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee ohh.. if thats the pblm.. `$('.btn-success').hide();` this would be wrk.. check edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it would appear I was trying to hide something that wasn't there :-) I trace where the buttons were being rendered and i was trying to hide them before they were drawn, dooooh

thanks for your input guys